# Is there an easy way to re-attach the end part of a bathroom pull light switch?

Tags: bathroom

In my bathroom, I have a light switch; pulling the string that is attached either turns the light on or off respectively. When doing this yesterday, the very end of the pull switch came off - the string is still attached and works without issue, but the very end part (the bit that people usually use to turn the light on/off without pulling the string directly) detached itself. Is there an easy way of either re-attaching the original, or will a new end part need to be purchased?

Comment: You mean the little doodad that weighs it down and gives something easy to grab onto?

Comment: This exactly! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are often held on by a knot, if you can open the doodad (assuming it is simply clipped shut) you will be able to thread the string through the hole and make a new knot. With a needle and thread or some glue you can stich/glue the knot to prevent it from undoing again.

There is no need to replace the string itself unless the string is what failed.

Comment: A figure 8 knot is far less prone to coming undone without any fastening. Manufacturers seem to like to put in overhand knots that can slowly walk off the end of the string.